# Common divisor theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I am reading Apostol's Mathematical analysis 2nd edition, and i am confused about theorem 1.6.

> ...If $d|a$ and $d|b$, we say $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$...
>
> Theorem 1.6
>
> Every pair of integers has a common divisor of the form $d=ax+by$ where
>   $x$ and $y$ are integers. Moreover, every common divisor of $a$ and $b$
>   divides this $d$.

(I haven't read the proof yet so please don't spoil it)

If $d$ divides $a$ and $b$, that means $d$ is less than $a$ and $b$. So how can $d$ be a linear combination of a and b? Is it backwards, and $a$ and $b$ are divisors of $d$?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ need not be both positive.

Comment: Can you think of a way to make $1$ using a linear combination of $3$ and $5$?

Comment: According to the theorem, if (3,5)=1 then 1=3*2 +5*(-1) and 1=5*2 + 3*(-3). Hope now you can move on to the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear combination can involve negative coefficients - that's why the quoted section states "$x$ and $y$ are **integers**" rather than "... are **natural numbers**".
For example, $d=2$ for ${a,b}={4,6}$, with $2=4×-1+6×1$.
Using the extension of Euclid's algorithm allows you to find the $x,y$ for the GCD, and from there it's a matter of substitution for smaller common divisors.

Comment: Or for a less trivial example, $d=3$, ${a,b}={9,15}$: $3=9×7+15×-4$.

Answer (score 1):

$d$ *can* be a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ because the $x$ and $y$ need not be both positive (in fact they won’t). When you read the proof, you’ll find that $d$ is the least positive integer than can be expressed as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.